# Should I avoid sending an update to the db every time a field inputs data

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, network-programming

I am trying to mimic some desktop software. The users are accustomed to never saving. The software saves as they change values.

I'm using blur and change events in jquery to trigger updates.

Clearly, this is going to use a lot of unnecessary bandwidth, but it does meet the requirements.

I have no problem doing this, but I want to ask if there is a clear, definitive reason not to do this?

Is there a clearly preferable alternative? Saving every few seconds for instance.

edit - I should note that the updates are segregated, so all of the data is not sent and received in each update. It may be up to 4 or 5 tables and 200 or so fields at once, but more typically, its a couple tables and 10 or so fields.

Comment: It looks like solution you have works for your case. Are you looking for excuses to redesign? Expect problems in near future? Looking to learn some particular framework? (Note that there are plenty of ways to do that and so far your question feels way too broad...)

Comment: I feel like I'm doing something that is unfamiliar and that I hadn't heard of others doing, so I wanted to ask around for advice.

Comment: I didn't answer your question - I am not trying to persuade others to redesign, I am trying to meet the requirements of a job. We've already chosen the framework.

Comment: Updating each field as they are edited is pretty standard MVVM behavior.

Comment: If you can get away with updates on every field (or maybe "row") change - go for it. Otherwise you'll run into all sorts of partial success cases and multi-way merge conflicts - explaining/showing such information to user is hard... You can experiment with updates on timer + listening for before close event on the page... but you need to carefully analyze what your requirements before implementing batching of updates/edits.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good thoughts - I hadn't thought of some of that. Thank you.

Comment: Keith. That answers my question. I develop by myself and sometimes wonder if I'm doing something obviously wrong. This helps me feel more comfortable with what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're exact requirement seems a little vague but, as far as I understand, you seem to be doing the correct thing.

You can refine things a bit if you wish:

1. **Serialization.** It's not the same to send data serialized as an XML compared to JSON. For better bandwidth save, JSON serialization is recommended.
2. **Encoding.** To correctly analyze bandwidth usage you could consider thinking about what kind of stuff you're sending to the backend. Does it make sense to send it plain?, could you take advantage of some compressing algorithm? Does doing this extra calculation makes a noticeable performance impact on your solution?
3. **Scheduling.** This really depends on your requirements, but does it really makes sense to sync on every change?. Can you take the risk of syncing in intervals and possible lose some changes?. This decision could make a huge impact on total bandwidth usage of your application.
4. **Local storage.** This really depends on how you should meet your requirements, but maybe you could take advantage of local storage in HTML5 depending on your decision regarding to 3. Just an idea.